# Замена символов в строке/ разбиение строки на символы/ действия над символами в СИ

Tags: c, строки

Дан цвет в формате rrggbb, где rr, gg, bb - две шестнадцатеричные цифры для соответствующего компонента цвета.

Необходимо произвести вычисления по формуле 0.3*R + 0.59*G + 0.11*B

Ввод содержит цвет формате rrggbb

Вывести одно целое число – результат вычислений по формуле, округленный к ближайшему целому числу.

ввод:
F0A092

ввыод:182

Comment: Что это означает `R = r+r`? Вы понимаете, как устроена входная строка? Например, 0xffff00 - это фиолетовый цвет

Comment: сумма двух шестнадцатеричных цифр

Comment: и чему она равна для моего примера или для вашего?

Comment: Извините, сейчас сам посчитал и понял, что я не правильно понял саму задачу. Задачу исправил.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy округление произведётся автоматически при приведении типов (обычно сопроцессор по умолчанию настроен на округление к ближайшему целому). Но если совсем уж надёжно: `output_number = round(0.3*R + 0.59*G + 0.11*B);`

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy может и без вещественной. Использовать арифметику FIX1616, например. А требуется ли это по заданию? В тз такого нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно научить [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) разбирать строку самостоятельно. `%2x` читает два шестнадцатеричных символа и сохраняет соответствующее им значение в беззнаковой переменной. Если читать из строки, то `sscanf` сделает тоже самое.

Для вычисления яркости вещественная арифметика не нужна. `+ 50` в конце суммы обеспечивает округление к ближайшему целому при делении на *100*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned r, g, b;
    if (scanf("%2x%2x%2x", &r, &g, &b) != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", (30 * r + 59 * g + 11 * b + 50) / 100);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.c
>
> $ echo F0A092 | ./a.out
> 182
> ```

Comment: Стоит заметить, что вариант формулы в числах с плавающей точкой `round(0.3*R + 0.59*G + 0.11*B)` не на всех входных данных даёт такой же результат, что и точная целочисленная версия. [Пример](https://godbolt.org/z/6obfW6T55).

Comment: @wololo, замечательный комментарий. 34942 случая различий. Не так мало, я  ожидал лучшего соответствия. Правка "округлению 0.5 к чётному" улучшения не даёт - не понимаю почему. Вообще задачу можно поставить так: как можно точнее имитировать поведение `double` в 32-xбитной целой арифметике.

Answer (score 0):

Копируете два нужных символа `strncpy` или вообще `memcpy` (не забывая место под завершающий нуль)

Преобразуете в целое, при этом добавляя префикс `0x` или указывая систему счисления 16, дальше уже арифметика простая

```
char hex[7] = "F0A04C";
char sub[3] =  {0};
strncpy(sub, hex+2, 2);
int G = (int)strtol(sub, NULL, 16);

printf("%d", G); //160
```

Comment: а как копировать два нужных символа?

Comment: Арифметика не нужна (`%2x`).

Comment: Арифметику я имел в виду по вычислению яркости, а вывод компонента можно в любом виде делать